# MVC OnSuccess Script error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My Parent form has the follwing link:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "ControllerAction", new { id=Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions
                       {
                           HttpMethod = "GET",
                           UpdateTargetId = "targetDiv",
                           InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,                           
                           OnSuccess = "openPopup()"
                       })
```

OpenPopup script function:

```
function openPopup() {
        $('#test').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 800,
            resizable: false,               
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
            }
        });
    }
```

In my partial view i have Ajax.BeginForm

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionGoesHere", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "selectedview", LoadingElementId = "spinner", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "CloseWindow" })) {....
```

}

```
<script type="text/javascript">    

    function CloseWindow() {
        $('#test').dialog("close");
    }



</script>
```

After successful operation, it suppose to close the dialog window.But i'm getting the following script error.

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'
```

Any clue?

Comment: try to call `openPopup()` in two views i.e;Parent view and Partial View

Answer (score 0):

You should first initialize the dialog means open the dialog box and then call the close .You need to call this sequence only,

```
openPopup() --->  CloseWindow()
```

Here code is

```
$(function() {
    function openPopup() {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            resizable: false,               
            modal: true,
            open: function (event, ui) {
            }
        });
    }
    function CloseWindow() {
        $('#dialog').dialog("close");
    }


    openPopup()
    CloseWindow() //first run comment it and second run remove comment

  });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

Demo link http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/6TssK/1/

Comment: Thank you for your response. If you look at my code, im calling the closewindow method after opened the dialog. So i think there is no issue with sequence. Since its MVC partial view, somehow the dialog is not getting initialized when i call the CloseWindow method. I tried assigning class name to dialog window, but that  didn't work.

Comment: @Yass first write your code inside `$(function() {})`. I think it is DOM problem.

Comment: @Yass I observed your code first call the `openPopup()` in your code, You didn't call the function ajax beginning, After Ajax success call the `CloseWindow()`

Comment: I have updated my question. Hope it gives an idea how im opening the window.